# Textarea into an array or implode?

Tags: php

Say I have a text area, user enters information exactly like styled below:

```
Ice cream
Chocolate
```

then submits this information, I want to retrieve the information EXACTLY like so:

```
Ice cream, Chocolate
```

Is this the best way to do it:

```
$arr = explode("\n", $var);
$arr = implode(",", $arr);
```

When doing it like this, it puts the information out like so:

```
Ice cream , Chocolate
```

Note the space after cream, will a simple `trim()` fix this?

Comment: is it TOO hard to check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace("~\s*[\r\n]+~", ', ', $text);
```

Comment: Thank you :) Thats a lot cleaner and works just how I want it.

Comment: How would I do this visa versa? Say I wanted to select "Ice cream, Chocolate" and convert it back to what it was originally, to display in the text area?

Comment: @Kyle R: uhm, it is not possible to convert back, since user can put several commas **in one line**. I always advice to store user's data as-is, without any modification and decorate in only when necessary (when you display) with necessary modifications applied. Is it appropriate for your case?

Comment: What do you suggest for me to enter data from each new line from the text area into one field on the table, and then echo it out back in the text area after insertion as how they entered it?

Comment: If you need to restore the data as it was - yes, just take from database and `echo` it as is (but don't forget to apply `htmlspecialchars()`). But not from **each line** - store **all the user input** as-is in one field (which is multi-lined string)

Comment: How would ucwords() work with this? As it perceives each new line as one whole word, not each seperate line as a new word.. so its only upper casing the first line.. not the second line as its counting it all as one word if you get what I mean?

Comment: @Kyle R: I can't get you mean :-S

Answer (score 1):

Dont store modified data in db, just store original one so when you present it to user they can edit them easily.

As far as displaying them, when you present output to users' browser use regex as mentioned by **zrekms** above

```
$text = preg_replace("~\s*[\r\n]+~", ', ', $text);
```

Above line is good enough.

Oh BTW for those who want to explode new line but dont know how because they are different on each OS, Instead of doing this...

```
$arr = explode("\n", $var);
$arr = explode("\r\n", $var);
$arr = explode("\r", $var);
```

Just use

```
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $var);
```

PHP_EOL is equivalent to new line char and its OS independent.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but will "\r\n"   in the explode correct the issue? I know in Windows Based machines a new line is just that.

Answer (score -2):

You could use preg_split with regular expressions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php